# How to ignore URLs with query strings (?xxx=xxx)

Tags: scrapy

I want my spider to ignore any URL that has a query string. I have tried adding an expression to the deny rules (for `\?`) in my LinkExtractor (see below) but it gets ignored ie. my spider is still crawling/extracting URLs that include the `?` character.

I only have 1 start URL which is the root of my domain so the only way to crawl links is via the LinkExtractor.

Here is the only rule in my CrawlSpider implementation.

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=(), 
            deny=(':443', ':80', '\?', )), 
            callback='parse_page', 
            follow=True),
)
```

URLs that include the port numbers are being excluded but any containing a `?` are still being included.

The [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) don't discuss this particular use case - at least I cannot find it.

Anyone have any ideas of how to exclude URLs that contain query strings from being extracted?

I am using Scrapy 1.4.0.

**UPDATE**

For some reason, scrapy seems to be ignoring any expressions containing the `?` character in the `deny` attribute of a LinkExtractor definition. I got an alternative approach of filtering the Links working however.

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=(), 
            deny=(':443', ':80', )),
            process_links='filter_links', 
            callback='parse_page', 
            follow=True),

    def filter_links(self, links):
        for link in links:
            if '?' in link.url:
                continue
            else:
                yield link
```

Comment: Try this pattern in deny `https?://(?:[^/]+/?)+\?.*` and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, scrapy hangs when I try and run the crawl with that deny rule.

Comment: how about `.*\?.*`

Comment: Ye, I already tried that and about another 10 different expressions. For some reason, scrapy seems to be ignoring any expression containing a `?`. I got an alternative approach working using a filter function - see update. Thanks for your time though.